# Ansible regex is wrong to add a block in a file

Tags: ansible, regex

I'd like to add a block between `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` and `</IfModule>` in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf` with the ansible task shown below. I use `blockinfile` and `insertbefore`.

Unfortunately the block is always added after `</IfModule>` at the bottom of the file. I guess my regex is wrong.

```
- name: Apache2 > update SSL conf
  become: yes
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
    block: |
      # Requires Apache >= 2.4
      SSLCompression off
      SSLUseStapling on
      SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"

      # Requires Apache >= 2.4.11
      SSLSessionTickets Off

      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains"
      Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
    marker: ""
    insertbefore: '^<\/IfModule>'
  notify:
    - Restart apache2
```

I have tried the following regex without success:

```
insertbefore: '/^<\/IfModule>/m'
insertbefore: "<\/IfModule>"
insertbefore: "</IfModule>"
insertbefore: "</IfModule> "
insertbefore: '^<\/IfModule>$'
insertbefore: "&lt;/IfModule&gt;"
insertbefore: '(?m)^<\/IfModule>\\s?$'
insertbefore: '^</IfModule>\s?$'
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me to fix my regex.
Thanks.

Comment: empty marker removes "ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK" lines as explained by this answer https://serverfault.com/a/755947/516504

Comment: I thought these lines made the code less readable so I got rid of them (after reading the how-to on SE). The link I put in my previous comment explains that it's recommended to keep these lines. I reconsidered it and put them back into the code. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Story**:
the winner regex is `insertbefore: "^</IfModule>\\s?$"`

**Long Story**:
I got another idea to get everything done:
- first, one task to remove `</IfModule>` at the bottom of the file
- second, one task to add the block at the bottom of the file
- third, one task to add `</IfModule>` at the bottom of the file

I wrote the first new task:

```
- name: Apache2 > Removes </IfModule>
  become: yes
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
    regexp: "^</IfModule>\\s?$"
    state: absent
```

and I realized I'd just written the right regex... My mistake was to escape `/`.
:-)

**Correct task that manages everything by itself:**

```
- name: Apache2 > update SSL conf
  become: yes
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
    block: |
      # Requires Apache >= 2.4
      SSLCompression off
      SSLUseStapling on
      SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"

      # Requires Apache >= 2.4.11
      SSLSessionTickets Off

      ## HSTS (mod_headers is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains"

      ## Transmit cookies over secure connection only
      Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
    insertbefore: "^</IfModule>\\s?$"
  notify:
    - Restart apache2
```

Anx's comment made me put back blockinfile markers to keep the task idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this for ansible blockinfile regex example

```
- name: 'NTP configuration for REHEL6 or CentOS6 or SUSE'
   blockinfile:
     path: /etc/ntp.conf
     insertafter: '^# Please'
     block: |
      server 10.121.127.12 iburst
      server 10.122.127.13 iburst
   when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "6") or (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "6")
```